# How to delete Content Area in Existing Template

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

I'm trying to create a new template based on an Existing (stock) Template in Content Builder. The stock template includes a "Pre Header" content area that I do not need. I deleted the content blocks within the area, but I'm still left with an empty Pre Header content area. How do I go about deleting this? I looked in Properties of the Content Area and do not see an option to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this without editing the code of the original template. However if a content block is left empty it shouldn't show up in your final email. If you go to preview/test tab the preheader content block should disappear, as well if you send a test email.